# Use CHARINDEX to find Value in other column always returns 1 record

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple table with

```
Location, PartNo, LookupPart
```

I am trying to find the PartNo that exist in the lookupPart column. Kinda like an excel Vlookup except I need to approximate and do other calculation in SQL.

I am using

```
    SELECT Part_No
    FROM Part_tbl 
    WHERE CHARINDEX(PartNo,LookupPart)>0
```

Both PartNo and LookupPart are a VARCHAR.

I am getting 1 record returned. 
 However, If I use:

```
     SELECT Part_No
     FROM Part_tbl 
     WHERE CHARINDEX('538',LookupPart)>0
```

I get 10+ records that start or contain '538'

What am I missing?

Comment: What does this give? `SELECT TOP(20) 'x' + Part_No + 'x' FROM Part_tbl WHERE CHARINDEX(LTRIM(RTRIM(PartNo)),LookupPart)>0`

Comment: And these: `select distinct top(20) part_no from Part_tbl order by 1` and `select distinct top(20) LookupPart from Part_tbl order by 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
SELECT Part_No
FROM Part_tbl t1
WHERE EXISTS (select 1 from Part_tbl t2 WHERE CHARINDEX(t1.PartNo,t2.LookupPart)>0)
```